# Batch updating an SQL table by month with multiple WHEREs

Tags: loops, t-sql, where-clause, batch-processing, yearmonth

I have a query where I am uncommenting and re-commenting in multiple WHERE clauses since I would like to update a table one month at a time.  See below sample WHERE clause:

```
update L
set
[skeySpotTypeTele] = COALESCE(ST.[skeySpotTypeTele], -1),
[skeySalesOptionTele] = COALESCE(SOT.[skeySalesOptionTele], -1)
FROM [BI_DWH_TELE].[dwh].[EDC_LIGNECAMPAGNE_FINAL] L
LEFT JOIN [dwh].[DimSpotTypeTele] ST ON L.[NO_CATEGORIEOCCASION] = ST.[SpotTypeID] AND ST.Source = 'T1' AND CAST(L.CALR_ID_JRDIFN AS date) >= ST.[scd_start] AND CAST(L.CALR_ID_JRDIFN AS date) < ST.[scd_end]
LEFT JOIN [dwh].[DimSalesOptionTele] SOT ON L.[NO_OPTIONVENTE] = SOT.[SalesOptionID] AND SOT.Source = 'T1' AND CAST(L.CALR_ID_JRDIFN AS date) >= SOT.[scd_start] AND CAST(L.CALR_ID_JRDIFN AS date) < SOT.[scd_end]


--2016
--where L.skeyDate >= 20151228 and L.skeyDate <= 20160131
where L.skeyDate >= 20160201 and L.skeyDate <= 20160229
--where L.skeyDate >= 20160301 and L.skeyDate <= 20160331
--where L.skeyDate >= 20160401 and L.skeyDate <= 20160430
--where L.skeyDate >= 20160501 and L.skeyDate <= 20160531
--where L.skeyDate >= 20160601 and L.skeyDate <= 20160630
--where L.skeyDate >= 20160701 and L.skeyDate <= 20160731
--where L.skeyDate >= 20160801 and L.skeyDate <= 20160831
--where L.skeyDate >= 20160901 and L.skeyDate <= 20160930
--where L.skeyDate >= 20161001 and L.skeyDate <= 20161031
--where L.skeyDate >= 20161101 and L.skeyDate <= 20161130
--where L.skeyDate >= 20161201 and L.skeyDate <= 20161231

--2017
--where L.skeyDate >= 20170101 and L.skeyDate <= 20170131
--where L.skeyDate >= 20170201 and L.skeyDate <= 20170228
--where L.skeyDate >= 20170301 and L.skeyDate <= 20170331
--where L.skeyDate >= 20170401 and L.skeyDate <= 20170430
--where L.skeyDate >= 20170501 and L.skeyDate <= 20170531
--where L.skeyDate >= 20170601 and L.skeyDate <= 20170630
--where L.skeyDate >= 20170701 and L.skeyDate <= 20170731
--where L.skeyDate >= 20170801 and L.skeyDate <= 20170831
--where L.skeyDate >= 20170901 and L.skeyDate <= 20170930
--where L.skeyDate >= 20171001 and L.skeyDate <= 20171031
--where L.skeyDate >= 20171101 and L.skeyDate <= 20171130
--where L.skeyDate >= 20171201 and L.skeyDate <= 20171231

--2018
--where L.skeyDate >= 20180101 and L.skeyDate <= 20180131
--where L.skeyDate >= 20180201 and L.skeyDate <= 20180228
--where L.skeyDate >= 20180301 and L.skeyDate <= 20180331
--where L.skeyDate >= 20180401 and L.skeyDate <= 20180430
--where L.skeyDate >= 20180501 and L.skeyDate <= 20180531
--where L.skeyDate >= 20180601 and L.skeyDate <= 20180630
--where L.skeyDate >= 20180701 and L.skeyDate <= 20180731
--where L.skeyDate >= 20180801 and L.skeyDate <= 20180831
--where L.skeyDate >= 20180901 and L.skeyDate <= 20180930
--where L.skeyDate >= 20181001 and L.skeyDate <= 20181031
--where L.skeyDate >= 20181101 and L.skeyDate <= 20181130
--where L.skeyDate >= 20181201 and L.skeyDate <= 20181231

--2019
--where L.skeyDate >= 20190101 and L.skeyDate <= 20190131
--where L.skeyDate >= 20190201 and L.skeyDate <= 20190228
--where L.skeyDate >= 20190301 and L.skeyDate <= 20190331
--where L.skeyDate >= 20190401 and L.skeyDate <= 20190430
--where L.skeyDate >= 20190501 and L.skeyDate <= 20190531
--where L.skeyDate >= 20190601 and L.skeyDate <= 20190630
--where L.skeyDate >= 20190701 and L.skeyDate <= 20190731
--where L.skeyDate >= 20190801 and L.skeyDate <= 20190831
--where L.skeyDate >= 20190901 and L.skeyDate <= 20190930
--where L.skeyDate >= 20191001 and L.skeyDate <= 20191031
--where L.skeyDate >= 20191101 and L.skeyDate <= 20191130
--where L.skeyDate >= 20191201 and L.skeyDate <= 20191231

--2020
--where L.skeyDate >= 20200101 and L.skeyDate <= 20200131
--where L.skeyDate >= 20200201 and L.skeyDate <= 20200229
--where L.skeyDate >= 20200301 and L.skeyDate <= 20200331
--where L.skeyDate >= 20200401 and L.skeyDate <= 20200430
--where L.skeyDate >= 20200501 and L.skeyDate <= 20200531
--where L.skeyDate >= 20200601 and L.skeyDate <= 20200630
--where L.skeyDate >= 20200701 and L.skeyDate <= 20200731
--where L.skeyDate >= 20200801 and L.skeyDate <= 20200831
--where L.skeyDate >= 20200901 and L.skeyDate <= 20200930
--where L.skeyDate >= 20201001 and L.skeyDate <= 20201031
--where L.skeyDate >= 20201101 and L.skeyDate <= 20201130
--where L.skeyDate >= 20201201 and L.skeyDate <= 20201231

--2021
--where L.skeyDate >= 20210101 and L.skeyDate <= 20210131
--where L.skeyDate >= 20210201 and L.skeyDate <= 20210228
--where L.skeyDate >= 20210301 and L.skeyDate <= 20210331
--where L.skeyDate >= 20210401 and L.skeyDate <= 20210430
--where L.skeyDate >= 20210501 and L.skeyDate <= 20210531
--where L.skeyDate >= 20210601 and L.skeyDate <= 20210630
--where L.skeyDate >= 20210701 and L.skeyDate <= 20210731
--where L.skeyDate >= 20210801 and L.skeyDate <= 20210831
--where L.skeyDate >= 20210901 and L.skeyDate <= 20210930
--where L.skeyDate >= 20211001 and L.skeyDate <= 20211031
--where L.skeyDate >= 20211101 and L.skeyDate <= 20211130
--where L.skeyDate >= 20211201 and L.skeyDate <= 20211231

--2022
--where L.skeyDate >= 20220101 and L.skeyDate <= 20220131
--where L.skeyDate >= 20220201 and L.skeyDate <= 20220228
--where L.skeyDate >= 20220301 and L.skeyDate <= 20220331
--where L.skeyDate >= 20220401 and L.skeyDate <= 20220430
--where L.skeyDate >= 20220501 and L.skeyDate <= 20220531
--where L.skeyDate >= 20220601 and L.skeyDate <= 20220630
--where L.skeyDate >= 20220701 and L.skeyDate <= 20220731
--where L.skeyDate >= 20220801 and L.skeyDate <= 20220831
--where L.skeyDate >= 20220901 and L.skeyDate <= 20220930
--where L.skeyDate >= 20221001
```

I am basically, doing a manual uncomment going down each of my WHERE clauses waiting for the query to complete its update for each month.

I would like to modify my update query in order to have more of a batch update to loop through each month.

Ideally, I would like to avoid using a loop in SQL and rather try to find another solution such as with a CTE.  I know that I might need to declare some start date and end date variables and perhaps defin a calendar of some sort in my CTE block?  I am looking for the most efficiant solution for a table with hundreds of millions of rows.

I am open to any sugestions.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with a clause like `[skeySalesOptionTele] = COALESCE(SOT.[skeySalesOptionTele], -1)`? It seems like you should also be filtering to `WHERE (skeySpotTypeTele IS NULL OR skeySalesOptionTele IS NULL)` as otherwise you're going to possibly be updating *millions* of rows to their same value. Perhaps if you filter to that, the number of rows you need to `UPDATE` are significantly less?

Comment: I think this is actually an appropriate use of a looping structure and your current manual process is, in fact, a loop (albeit one with you performing the looping action.

Comment: @Larnu, they're the 2 new columns with NULL everywhere. I'm just using the coalesce to make sure that we have a value everywhere, in case somehow there is a value missing in one of the 2 new dims.  I have modified my query with the corresponding joins to those dimensions.  Let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: I believe Larnu's point is that if your goal is to eliminate `NULL`s from your table, then you don't need to `UPDATE` the rows that aren't `NULL`. You can therefore add a predicate to your `WHERE` clause to limit to only those rows that are `NULL` and ignore a potentially sizable number of rows during the `UPDATE`

Comment: *"they're the 2 new columns with NULL everywhere"* So are you saying that *every* row has the value `NULL` in both those columns? Then why the `COALESCE` and not just `= -1`?

Comment: It would be impossible, from the question as posed, for anyone to know that you added two columns to an existing table are are now wanting to assign values for them to all columns.

Comment: If this is a new column, why didn't you create it with a `DEFAULT` value and tell the RDBMS to create the column with said default value? That would be ***SIGNIFICANTLY*** more performant.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information.  These are new columns, but there were 2 new stored procedures executed which added some values to those columns.  Some of the values could also be missing. therefore, I had needed to use the COALESCE instead of simply assigning a -1 directly.

Comment: I was simply trying to find a faster way to do my multiple WHERE clauses and avoid doing the manual un-commenting and recommenting.

Comment: To emphasise *how* significantly more performant `ADD`ing it with a `DEFAULT` value is, for a table I created with 10 million rows, it took my sandbox instance  over **4 minutes** to `ADD` the column and then `UPDATE` it with the value `-1` (`ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD Col1 int NULL;`, `UPDATE dbo.SomeTable SET Col1 = -1;`) . To add a column with a default and populated value (`ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD Col2 int CONSTRAINT DF_Col2 DEFAULT -1 WITH VALUES NULL;`) it took 3ms; it was *almost* 95,000 times faster...